# Best way to wakeup multiple thread using pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have created 4 threads by `pthread_create`. I want them to start running at the very same time, so I add `sem_wait(&sem)` at the very beginning of the thread procedure. In main thread, I may using something like this, but I don't think it is a good solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    sem_post(&sem);
}
```

I googled and found `pthread_cond_t`. However, `pthread_cond_broadcast` can only wake up threads that are currently waiting. Even if I put `pthread_cond_wait` at the very beginning of the procedure, it is still not guaranteed that `pthread_cond_wait` is called before `pthread_cond_broadcast` (in main thread).

To avoid this, I have to add lots of additional codes to make sure the calling sequence of `wait` and `broadcast`, which is also not smart.

So, is there a simple way to 'line-up' all threads (make them start to run at the same time)?

There seems to be a `sem_post_multiple`, but it is a win32 extension in pthread. I am using Linux (Android) however.

Answer (score 3):

you are searching for a barrier

> pthread_barrier_t

you initialize it with the number of threads (n) and then call pthread_barrier_wait() with every thread. This call will block the execution until n threads have reached the barrier.

example:

```
int num_threads = 4;
pthread_barrier_t bar;

void* thread_start(void* arg) {
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar);
    //...
}
int main() {
    pthread_barrier_init(&bar,NULL,num_threads);
    pthread_t thread[num_threads];
    for (int i=0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(thread + i, NULL, &thread_start, NULL);
    }
    for (int i=0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
    pthread_barrier_destroy(&bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I want. Android NDK does not support pthread_barrier_t, but one can implement it according to this simplified version: [simplified pthread_barrier_t](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/google-breakpad/src.git/+/85e1fdcdc1029741a49d91b2e03e5d14aeee2765/common/android/testing/pthread_fixes.h)

Comment: most of the synchronisation-structured can be build with the other tools, basically you only need mutex and cond.-variables